# How to particular character at specific location in java string

Tags: java, string

I have a java String which contains the `value >00:01:00`. I need to remove the **sign** of "**>**" from this string but I am not able to achieve this.

I am using following code to achieve the target,

```
String duration = "value >00:01:00";
duration.substring(8, duration.length() - 9);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also do like this

```
duration = duration.replace(">", "").trim();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
String duration = ">00:01:00";
duration = duration.substring(duration.indexOf('>') + 1, duration.length()); // substring from index of that char to a specific length(I've used the length as the end index)
duration = duration.substring(duration.indexOf('>') + 1); // substring from index of that char to the end of the string (@DanielBarbarian's suggestion)
```

Get the substring from the index of that particular character(you need the +1 as you need the substring from the next index) to the end of the String.

You could replace that particular character as well, if you don't want to extract a substring as such.

```
String duration = ">00:01:00";
duration = duration.replace(">", "");
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but if you just want the rest of the String from the starting index you can just use duration.substring(duration.indexOf('>') + 1)

Comment: Your solution will give compilation error because if you see replace method it takes char as parameter not string.  :P

Comment: Your are right bro. I wrote first that but i change it later seeing the docs but char parameter takes space and not '', thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 String duration = ">00:01:00";
 duration = duration.replace(">","");
 System.out.println(duration);
```

Comment: I wrote first correct then i change to ''...you are right bro

Answer (score 2):

You can do in following ways :

#### 1. public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)

```
String duration = ">00:01:00";
duration = duration.substring(duration.indexOf('>') + 1, duration.length());
```

#### 2. public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)

```
String duration = ">00:01:00";
duration = duration.replace('>', '');
```

#### 3. Using public String substring(int beginIndex)

```
String duration = ">00:01:00";
duration = duration.substring(duration.indexOf('>') + 1);
```

#### 4. Using public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)

```
String duration = ">00:01:00";
duration = duration.replaceFirst(">", "");
```

#### 5. Using public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)

```
String duration = ">00:01:00";
duration = duration.replaceAll(">", "");
```

### OUTPUT

```
00:01:00
```

Comment: Same here as in R.J's solution: Your solution is correct but if you just want the rest of the String from the starting index you can just use duration.substring(duration.indexOf('>') + 1)

Comment: Is there something called an empty character?!

Answer (score 1):

`duration .substring(duration.length() - 8);` Should remove the > sign.

Comment: duration.length() is 9 in the example given, so what you are returning is duration.substring(0), which is the original string unchanged.

Comment: Ok its a copy paste mistake. The string i considered was ">00:01:00."

Answer (score 0):

```
 String duration = ">00:01:00";
  //Method 1
  String result = duration.replace(">", "");
  System.out.println(result);

  //Method 2
  String result2 = duration.substring(1);
  System.out.println(result2);

  //Method 3
  /***
   * Robust method but requires these imports
   * import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   * import java.util.regex.Pattern;
   */
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})") ;
  Matcher m = p.matcher(duration);
  if (m.find())
  { 
     String result3 = m.group(1);
     System.out.println(result3);
  }
```